# Do attraction and repulsion forces occur in quantum mechanic framework or everything is wave interaction and probability?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability

I thought quanta means discrete something like the package of energy for example a photon but the more I read about quantum mechanics especially the mathematic, wave interaction and probability keep on popping up. I just want to know how does wave interaction and probability explain attraction and repulsion forces? Let me rephrase: How does the probabilistic nature of constructive and destructive interferences of waves translate into attraction and repulsion of say electromagnetic forces? btw have I ditched classical mechanic in this question or I have to get rid of the idea of attraction and repulsion forces too?